# Fetch data from multiple tables and Insert into another table JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am a beginner in JPA. As per requirement I am trying to fetch data from multiple tables (Feeder,Monthlyfeederdetails) and insert into another table (Report). Can someone please show me the way to do it. I have looked at a few sql examples like

INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;

but how do I reference the different tables in one repository?

I need to get the feeder_name, feeder_type from Feeder table
and duration_of_intr,no_of_afcon from Monthlyfeederdetails table
and also the the (duration_of_intr * no_of_afcon)

in the third table i.e Report table

Feeder Model

```
@Entity
public class Feeder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int feeder_id;
    private String feeder_name;
    private int feeder_type;
    private int no_of_consumer_in_the_feeder;
 
}

Getters and setters
```

Monthlyfeederdetails Model

```
@Entity
public class Monthlyfeederdetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private int user_id; 
    private int feeder_id;
    private int feeder_type;
    //private int no_of_con_in_feeder;
    private int duration_of_intr; //duration of interruption
    private int freq_of_intr; //frequency of interruption;
    private int no_of_afcon; //no of consumer affected due to shutdown
    private int month;
    private int year;
}

Get and Set
```

Report Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "report of caifi and caidi")
public class Report {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int reportid;
    private String feeder_name;
    private int feeder_type;
    private int no_of_afcon;
    private int duration_of_intr;
    private int no_of_afconXduration_of_intr;
```

How can i achieve that?